# What do you call the number assigned to official documents at the university?

Tags: word-request, abbreviations

I wonder what you call the number that's assigned to an official document when it's archived – more precisely I'm wondering about official documents at the university, like strategic plans, appointment procedures etc.

*Reference number*? *Journal number*? *Registration number*? Something else entirely? Also, how do you abbreviate it?

Thank you!

Comment: The name given to what may be loosely called 'reference numbers' varies depending on the agency or organisation.

Comment: This will depend on the type of document. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer will be specific to the organisation concerned.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica I'm wondering specifically about official documents at the university, like strategic plans, appointment procedures etc

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, I see your point, but I really, really hope someone will be able to answer my question now that I've specified it. In my own language, it's the same word (and the same abbreviation) regardless of organisation, so I didn't know I wasn't specific enough..

Comment: Where I work,we have Case Reference Numbers, Payroll Numbers, Document References, Pension Numbers, and a lot more. They are all 'reference numbers' in a general sense. Universities, to be specific, in English speaking countries probably use their own terms. Chasly's answer is the best you are going to get.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey – yes, her answer is perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the most general term, "**reference number**".

Journal number and Registration number are much more specific.

An abbreviation might be **Ref.No.** or **Ref. No.** or similar.

**Example**

> Ref. No. : 20/06964/FULL Proposal
>
> https://www.westminster.gov.uk/sites/default/files/rec-20-11-08-all.pdf

[image]